# How can I display the image that was selected in a file browser with PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, display, pysimplegui

I'm trying to simply display an image after it's been browsed for through the FileBrowser, such as:
[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
   [ sg.Text("Choose your image: "), sg.FileBrowse(key = "chosen_img")],
   [ sg.Image(data = None, key = "img_display")],
]

window = sg.Window("Image displayer", layout)

while True:

event, values = window.read()

if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
   break

if event == "chosen_img":
   sg.Image.update(data = values["chosen_deck_img"])
```

I tried updating the 'data' of "img_display" for the values of "chosen_img" (which should be the path), but nothing appears.

Comment: It's easy to see you're creating a new Image object and not updating the existing one. Change: 1. Add `img = sg.Image(data = None, key = "img_display")` before layout, 2. Change to `layout = [
   [ sg.Text("Choose your image: "), sg.FileBrowse(key = "chosen_img")],
   img,
]`, 3. Use `img.update(data = values["chosen_deck_img"])`

Comment: I get this error:

Comment: what error?????

Comment: The text I posted doesn't show? Let me try again.

Comment: Error creating Window layout
Your row is not an iterable (e.g. a list)

Instead of a list, the type found was <class 'PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Image'>

The offensive row = 
<PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Image object at 0x0191E930>

This item will be stripped from your layout

Comment: Ooops, change to `layout = [[sg.Text("Choose your image: "), sg.FileBrowse(key = "chosen_img")], [img],]`

Comment: Ok, I tried that but nothing happens when the image is selected. The path appears as it normally would but the image itself doesn't appear. Am I supposed to set dimensions or something beforehand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242964/discussion-between-faindirnomainzein-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1):

`Filebrowse` won't generate event to your event loop, but update the content of `target`. Default `target` is `(ThisRow, -1)` which means previous element at same row. Most of time we will place one Input element before it to keep result of file browse and another button to load the file.

What the `values["chosen_deck_img"]` ? event or key, `"chosen_deck_img"`, not defined in your code.

So there're some issues found in your code:

- No event generated after you browse file,
- The event to update or show the image, not defined.
- The instance of Image element to be updated, not the class of Image element.

Following code disable Input to avoid any keyboard input and call `popup_get_file` by the button `Browse` clicked, also resize image to fit Image when shown in window.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def image_to_data(im):
    """
    Image object to bytes object.
    : Parameters
      im - Image object
    : Return
      bytes object.
    """
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

width, height = size = 640, 480    # Scale image
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Choose your image file: ")],
    [sg.Input(expand_x=True, disabled=True, key='File'), sg.Button('Browse')],
    [sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Status')],
    [sg.Image(size=size, background_color='green', key = "Image")],
]
window = sg.Window("Image displayer", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == "Browse":
        path = sg.popup_get_file("", no_window=True)
        if path == '':
            continue
        window['Status'].update('')
        window['File'].update(path)
        if not Path(path).is_file():
            window['Status'].update('Image file not found !')
            continue
        try:
            im = Image.open(path)
        except UnidentifiedImageError:
            window['Status'].update("Cannot identify image file !")
            continue
        w, h = im.size
        scale = min(width/w, height/h, 1)
        if scale != 1:
            im = im.resize((int(w*scale), int(h*scale)))
        data = image_to_data(im)
        window['Image'].update(data=data, size=size)

window.close()
```

[image]